# Marshaling, StringBuilder, and char pointer in DllImport

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport, stringbuilder

I was looking at SoundTouchWrapper for .NET and I saw this:

```
[DllImport (SoundTouchDLLName)]
internal static extern void soundtouch_getVersionString2 (StringBuilder versionString, int bufferSize);
```

And in the header file from the orginal C++ library:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall soundtouch_getVersionString2(char* versionString, int bufferSize);
```

Where can I read about how it works? How StringBuilder passed to this function is filled with data?

Comment: Using StringBuilder for fixed-lenght strings is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx in the Fixed-Lenght String Buffers section.

Comment: I understand now. Add your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The called libraray expects a pointer to a char-array with the size of `bufferSize` to write the text to.

```
soundtouch_getVersionString2(char* versionString, int bufferSize);
```

So you need a mutable object with predefined size that you can pass to the C++ library. Here the `StringBuilder` comes in place. Put it simple: since the usage of the memory of StringBuilder and the char-array is similiar, the caller can treat it as a char-array and fill it the common way.

Then use the function this way:

```
int bufferSize = 50;
StringBuilder versionString = new StringBuilder(" ", bufferSize);
soundtouch_getVersionString2(versionString, bufferSize);
string realString = versionString.ToString(); //convert it to unmutable stringstring
```